# Narcissus's mirage, Loki master piece

Tags: magic, humans

One fine day Loki, god of mischief decided to play a prank on humanity by casting a permanent spell on each and every human being alive, this spell is called "Narcissus's mirage" and here how it's work:

A) The shorter the distances between any two people the stronger the magic will pull them together.

Meaning if I were to stand shoulder to shoulder with you no force in the known universe can separate us physically.

B) A person desire will influence multiplicatively to the magic.

Meaning if both people stucked together desired to be separated will ends up in more agony and discomfort. Unless both develops a crush on each other can they free themselves! Works on any combination of sexes.

C) As long as any one desires to be together with any person alive on Earth the effect of Narcissus's mirage will continue to exist.

Meaning doomsday has been carried forward!

My question is if everyone knows the trick will humanity still be in danger of collapsing? Or will true love overcomes any obstacle? Will you still believe in love?

Comment: So wanting another person is the only way to free oneself but *also* the thing that keeps the spell going? Is the only way to beat it to want each other when we are trapped, then get far away from each other and only stop wanting one another when we are far enough apart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume this quality of existence happens spontaneously and see what happens. For simplicity, we'll focus our attention on New York City at 12-noon.

There's about [350,000 people walking in Times Square each day](http://cityroom.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/12/06/you-like-walking-in-the-city-so-do-plenty-of-others/?_r=0), which averages to about four people entering each second. According to Google Maps, it takes about a minute to walk from W 46th to W 47th street (one edge of Times Square). So we wind up with about 240 people in Times Square at any one time after the first minute. (This assumes no one stops to shop, chat, or gets held up by traffic lights.)

### First Second

The 240 people (I'll assume none of these are in love with each other) in Times Square accelerate towards each other at phenomenal speeds, somewhere around the strength of attraction just outside the event horizon of a black hole. All these people die due to the sudden negative acceleration at the end of the short journey. We're left with a giant ball of human corpses sitting in the middle of Times Square. (Not to mention any unfortunate dogs, shopping bags, and cars that are dragged along by the flying humans.)

### First Minute

We now have large balls of human debris all over the world. In New York City, an uneven distribution of kinetic energy from the inbound debris causes our debris ball to start rolling. It moves down the street and meets up with another debris ball. They crush together to form a larger sphere and continue rolling in a new direction.

### Cutting it Short

Things are getting pretty gruesome, but we don't really care anymore. The majority of the world's population is dead within the first minute. If we assume magical pull exists regardless where in the world a human is, then our debris balls will eventually gather up every human and countless debris items and, in the end, all merge together to form one giant human debris ball.

I don't know how much matter would be contained in the final debris ball, but I'm pretty certain I could find a few moons in the Solar System that would be smaller.

### To Answer Your Questions

> if everyone knows the trick will humanity still be in danger of collapsing?

Yes. The only way we don't all die from this is if *everyone* unconditionally loves everyone else all the time *before* the magic goes into effect. Which, were that to be the case, we would all accelerate *away* from each other at the same speed as we would have been attracted to each other and fly off into space (and die anyway). (This suggests there is a very fine balancing point somewhere in the middle.)

> Or will true love overcomes any obstacle?

No. We're all dead, so we can't experience love anymore. This question is useless in the face of this scenario.

> Will you still believe in love?

Again, no. I'm dead. I will, however, remember to take a number to punch Loki in the mouth when I get to Valhalla. ...and hope this magical influence doesn't extend to people in the afterlife.

Comment: This spell isn't like Newton laws of universal gravitation, even if it is the value of the constant will be negligible. Can you revise your answer the death tolls isn't necessary there's no science tag so go easy on the working mechanism of the spell will ya?

Comment: @user6760 From your question, "The shorter the distances between any two people the stronger the magic will pull them together. Meaning if I were to stand shoulder to shoulder with you no force in the known universe can separate us physically." The only thing I could think to compare this to was the gravitational pull of a black hole.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain?

Comment: Loki: "Ha ha, the humans will never expect this. Whoops, killed them all."